# How to append error from Get-ADComputer to table?

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I am trying to query multiple computers from the Domain using Get-ADComputer. I would like to append the pc name I queryed to the array with the word "error" or a nonsensical date or even a blank value in that spot.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$PCNames = "laptop-namea", "laptop-nameb", "laptop-badname"
$Output = @()
$Output = foreach ($PC in $PCNames) {
    try {
        Get-ADComputer -Identity $PC -Properties * |
            Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate
    } catch {
        $Output += ($PC)
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
Name         LastLogonDate        
----         -------------        
LAPTOP-NAMEA 1/27/2019 10:37:13 AM
LAPTOP-NAMEB 1/22/2019 8:23:02 AM
```

Wanted/expected output:

```
Name           LastLogonDate        
----           -------------        
LAPTOP-NAMEA   1/27/2019 10:37:13 AM
LAPTOP-NAMEB   1/22/2019 8:23:02 AM 
LAPTOP-BADNAME
```

Comment: instead of the `Select-Object`, save the info to a $Var, then build a PSCustomObject with the props you want ... and - if the saved $Var is blank - put a message in a `Status` property.

Answer (score 1):

[`Try` - `Catch` - `Finally` blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6) handle **terminating** errors. Apply the common parameter `-ErrorAction -Stop` as follows:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$PCNames = "laptop-namea","laptop-nameb","laptop-badname"
$Output = ForEach ($PC in $PCNames) 
    {
        try{
            Get-ADComputer -Identity $PC -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop | 
                Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate
            } 
        catch{
            [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$PC;LastLogonDate=$null}
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-Filter` instead of `-Identity` to avoid throwing errors in case of invalid names.

```
$Output = foreach ($PC in $PCNames) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Name'      = $PC
        'LastLogon' = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$PC'" -Property LastLogonDate |
                      Select-Object -Expand LastLogonDate
    }
}
```

Beware that querying AD for each individual computer is time-consuming. If the number of queries grows beyond a certain point it's better to query all computers, put them into an appropriate data structure (usually a hashtable), and then look up the desired information in that data structure.

```
$computers = @{}
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Property LastLogonDate | ForEach-Object {
    $computers[$_.Name] = $_.LastLogonDate
}

$Output = foreach ($PC in $PCNames) {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Name'      = $PC
        'LastLogon' = $computers[$PC].LastLogonDate
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to remove the errors, I would like to keep them in the output just denote that they have some kind of error